# Magento 2 - You need more permissions to create a backup

Tags: permissions, backup, magento2

I got this message when I tried to create a system backup in my Magento 2 installation. Does anyone know how to solve it? I am using admin master, it does not make any sense.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a permission issue. Please give permission as per document 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-backup.html

Thank you.